# how to fetch the id from json on the item click listener in AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, autocompletetextview

I want to fetch RouteId in onItemClick in AdapterView. (AutoCompleteTextView)
name and id i got in response, but not getting inside the clicklistener.

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, String.valueOf(jsonObject1));
                    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
                    Request request = new Request.Builder().header("Authorization", basicAuth).url(tUrl).post(requestBody).build();
                    Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
                    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(
                                            new Runnable() {
                                                public void run() {

                                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Request to the server failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                            Log.e("tag_response ", "onResponse(): " + response);

                            StatusLine statusLine = null;
                            result = response.body().string();
                            Log.e("tag_Result","Result "+result);

                            try {

                                routeData = new JSONArray(result);
                                for (int i=0; i<routeData.length(); i++){
                                    jsonRoute = routeData.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String userId = jsonRoute.getString("UserID");
                                    routeId = jsonRoute.getString("RouteId");
                                    routeName = jsonRoute.getString("RouteName");
                                    routeList.add(routeName);
                               //     Log.e("tag_routename", routeName);
                                }




                            }catch (Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        }
                    });
```

```
 final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, routeList);
            //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView
            autoRoute.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
            autoRoute.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
            autoRoute.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


            autoRoute.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    RouteName  =  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Log.e("tag_name", RouteName);


                    Routeid = adapter.getItem(routeList.get(position).indexOf(routeId));
                    Log.e("Routeid",Routeid);
                    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getBaseContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus()
                                    .getWindowToken(),
                            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Selected " + routeList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

```
[
    {
        "UserID": 0,
        "RouteId": 7,
        "RouteName": "Agra - Gurgaon"
    },
    {
        "UserID": 0,
        "RouteId": 40,
        "RouteName": "Ajmer - Gurgaon"
    },
    {
        "UserID": 0,
        "RouteId": 53,
        "RouteName": "Aligarh - Gurgaon"
    },
    {
        "UserID": 0,
        "RouteId": 58,
        "RouteName": "Allahabad - Gurgaon"
    },
    {
        "UserID": 0,
        "RouteId": 86,
        "RouteName": "Alwar - Gurgaon"
    }
]
```

I have a problem in this line :

```
Routeid = adapter.getItem(routeList.get(position).indexOf(routeId));
```

Comment: what is the value passed inside `.indexOf(routeId)`

Comment: routeId = jsonRoute.getString("RouteId");

Comment: You want to get `RouteId` of the click position?

Comment: yes............

Comment: Ok, then make list of `RouteId` as you made for `RouteName` and use the position inside `onItemClick` to get RouteId

Comment: Make a model class with `UserID`,`RouteId` and `RouteName`. Make a custom adapter and pass the list to that adapter. Then you can get the model item for your clicked position.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make one Model class of `Route` as below.

```html
public class Route 
{
 public String name;
 public String routeId;
 public String getname() 
 {
    return name;
 }
 public void setname(String name) 
 {
    this.name = name;
 }
 public String getRouteId() 
 {
    return routeId;
 }
 public void setRouteId(String routeId) 
 {
    this.routeId = routeId;
 }
}
```

Then you have to prepare one object of this class and add to list.

**Try this code in `onResponse` method where you have prepare your list. And pass this list in adapter.**

```html
//Define List of type 'Route'
List<Route> routeList = new ArrayList();

routeData = new JSONArray(result);
for (int i=0; i<routeData.length(); i++){
   Route route = new Route(); 
   jsonRoute = routeData.getJSONObject(i);
   String userId = jsonRoute.getString("UserID");
   routeId = jsonRoute.getString("RouteId");
   routeName = jsonRoute.getString("RouteName");
   route.setName(routeName);
   route.setRouteId(routeId);
   routeList.add(route);
}
```

**Now you can get routeId in your adapter onclick method like this**

```html
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
    RouteName  =  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Log.e("tag_name", RouteName);

    Routeid = routeList.get(position).getRouteId; //Change this line
    Log.e("Routeid",Routeid);
    
    //other code as it is.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use volley library for Json request

```
List<Route_data> list= new ArrayList();


autocompletetextview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           String Routeid = list.get(position).routeId();
            StringRequest str1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        Jsonarray array=obj.getJSONArray();

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                     list.add(new Route_data(routeName,routeId,route);   
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
            Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(str1); 
        }
    });

  class Route_data{
        public String routeName;
        public String routeId;
        public String route;

        public list_set(String routeName, String routeId, String route) {
            this.routeName= routeName;
            this.routeId= routeId;
            this.route= route;
        }

        public int routeName() {
            return img;
        }

        public String routeId() {
            return rate;
        }

        public String route() {
            return pro_name;
        }

    }
```